# Per-thread locale in linux

Tags: c, linux, internationalization

Is it possible to specify per-thread in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `setlocale(3)` changes it for the whole process.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you kinda can do that. However not per-thead, but only per-call, using locale_t structures.

Read more about that at POSIX:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/newlocale.html

And Ulrich Dreppper's dedsgin documents of what whent into glibc 2.1:

http://people.redhat.com/drepper/tllocale.ps.gz

Comment: `uselocale` ( http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html# ) does let you set a thread-local locale.